# Why does my UserForm Data enter in to a new file? (i.e I open Filename, and data is compiled in Filename1)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to keep all data within the same file, as it's on a shared network at work. For some reason once data is entered through the UserForm and is compiled in the worksheet, it doesn't all compile in to my original worksheet, but in to a new one that is in .xlsx

Is there somewhere I can add in that it remain in the same file?

The code I have connected to the command button is as follows:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rw As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet2 active
Sheet2.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: You "Dim" a variable, including `ws`,  but you don't  it - why not? Nor do you specify where `Cells(...` is lcoated (on which worksheet). Start by specifying in which worksheet `Cells` are located.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheet2.Activate`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rw As Range 

    Set rw = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).EntireRow

    With rw
        .Cells(1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
        .Cells(3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
        .Cells(4).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
        .Cells(5).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
        .Cells(6).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
    End With

End Sub
```